# Angular : ng build fails but npm run build works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Inside my Angular 5 app , i ve `angular-cli 1.6.8`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "karma": "ng test",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:ci": "jest --runInBand",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.12.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "npm": "^5.2.0",
    "proxy-polyfill": "^0.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.3.5",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jest": "^20.0.5",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^20.0.7",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
}
```

when running ng --version or ng build inside my app folder , it fails saying that : `bash: ng: command not found`  -> in contrats running `npm run build` runs normally

i ve **node 8.0.0** and **npm 4.2.2** installed globally , buti ve not **angular-cli** installed globally , and i don't want to install it. therfore i think that i may use ng commands inside my app (locally) , no ?

if not how may i do it without installing it globally via `npm install -g @angular/cli`  **(as i m not allowed to run global npm install actions)**

Sugesstions?

Comment: `npm run build` works because it calls `./node_modules/.bin/ng`. You could just `alias` that, or symlink it into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. I had been looking for this. Saved my day!!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `ng` command as well other commands, you need to install them globally. You can't run local commands because *NodeJS* does not find them.